# ggplotly tooltip showing NA value

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, na, ggplotly

I am developing my first app using R-shiny. I am using ggplotly to make interactive plots. For some reason, the tooltip shows the numerical value as NA. I am trying to calculate the sum of people who died in civilian aircraft and military aircraft each year.

My UI code is:

```
aircrash <-read.csv("aircrash_clean_data.csv", header = T)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
     navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                           "Aircrash Investigation Analysis", id="nav",
                tabPanel("Crashes",
                         sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("yearInput", "Year", min=1908, max=2020, 
                value=c(1908, 2020), sep=""),
    checkboxGroupInput("aircrafttypeInput", "Select the Aircraft Type:",
                       choices = c("Civilian",
                                   "Military"),
                       selected = c("Civilian", "Military"))
    
                                        
),
mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("Aircrafttypecount"),
    br(), br(),
    plotlyOutput("fatalitiesplot")
)
)
)
)    
)
```

My server code is:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    
    d1 <- reactive({
            aircrash %>%
            filter(crash_opr_type %in% input$aircrafttypeInput,
                   crash_year >= input$yearInput[1],
                   crash_year <= input$yearInput[2],)
        
    }) 
    
    output$Aircrafttypecount <-renderPlotly({
       
        a1<-ggplot(data=d1(), aes(x= crash_year, y=stat(count), color =crash_opr_type ))+
            geom_line(stat = "count")+theme_bw()+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), 
                  axis.title.x =element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))+
            labs(y = "Number of Aircrashes",x="Year",title = "Number of Crashes per Year",color = "Aircraft Type")+
            expand_limits(y=c(0,100)) + 
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20))+theme(legend.title = element_blank())
        ggplotly(a1, source = "select", tooltip = c("crash_year","count"))
        
    })
    
    output$fatalitiesplot <-renderPlotly({
        
        a2<-ggplot(data=d1(), aes(x= crash_year, y=fatalities, color=crash_opr_type ))+
            geom_line(stat="summary", fun=sum) +theme_bw()+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), 
                  axis.title.x =element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))+
            labs(y = "Number of Aircrashes",x="Year",title = "Number of Crashes per Year",color = "Aircraft Type")+
       theme(legend.title = element_blank())
        ggplotly(a2, source = "select", tooltip = c("crash_year","fatalities"))
        
    })
    
}
```

[image: Tooltip showing NA]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for each year in your data there are multiple values of `fatalities`, because multiple crashes per year. `tooltip` only accepts single values per point, so it just returns `NA` because it doesn't know how to process multiple values.

Simplest fix is to create a separate reactive after `d1`:

```
d2 <- reactive({
  d1() %>%
    group_by(crash_opr_type, crash_year) %>%
    summarise(fatalities = sum(fatalities,na.rm = TRUE))
})
```

Then for the plot `a2`, use `d2()` instead of `d1()`:

```
a2<-ggplot(data=d2(), aes(x= crash_year, y=fatalities, color=crash_opr_type))+
  geom_line() +theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x =element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(y = "Number of Aircrashes",x="Year",title = "Number of Crashes per Year",color = "Aircraft Type")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
ggplotly(a2, source = "select", tooltip = c("crash_year","fatalities"))
```

I also removed the `stat="summary", fun=sum` arguments of `geom_line()` since they are no longer necessary.